# Laravel 5.7: Custom attributes for form validation not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I'd like to validate a form using both custom messages and attributes. Instead of `name: The name may not be greater than 20 characters.` the user should see `Name: Please use fewer characters.`, for example.

I'm using AJAX and both keys and values of the `response.data.errors` object that Laravel returns. Im using Laravel 5.7.

This is a simplified version of the `validator` function in my `RegisterController`.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    // Nice attribute names
    $attributes = [
        'name' => 'Name',
        // ...
    ];

    // Custom messages
    $messages =  [
        'max' => 'Please use fewer characters.'
        // ...
    ];

    // Rules
    $rules = [
        'name'=> 'required|max:20',
        // ...
    ];

    // Working for messages, but not for attribute names
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages, $attributes);

    // Also not working
    // $validator->setAttributeNames($attributes);

    return $validator;
}
```

When there's a validation error, the user get's a message like `name: Please use fewer characters.`. That means the message from my custom array is displayed, but the default attribute name is used. What's wrong here?

Comment: Grammatical nitpick: "Please use **less** milk" (uncountable), "Please use **fewer** characters" (countable).

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I actually wrote 'less characters'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes do not replace key names, they are used to change the appearance of a key within a message - i.e `The Name field is required` - to achieve what you're trying to do in your question you'll need to create a new data array.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $data = [
        'Name' => $data['name'] ?? '',
        // ...
    ];

    // ...

    Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect this. Your solution is working fine. I expected I'd have to reverse the whole thing in the `create` method (`'name' => $data['Name']`), but that was not the case.

Answer (score 1):

use [Laravel Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation), scroll down to `Customizing The Error Messages` section. Check out the below sample code.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class UserRegistrationForm extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:20',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.max' => 'Please use less characters'
        ];
    }
}
```

In controller

```
public function register(UserRegistrationForm $request)
    {
         // do saving here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is coming from validation.php located in resources/Lang/xx/

EDIT :

You'll have to use

`$messages = [
    'name.max' => 'Your sentence here',
];`

Comment: You're wrong about the _messages_: Something like `'max' => 'Your sentence here'` is fine if you want to display the same message for all validations of the `max` rule. But my question concerns the _attributes_ anyway.

Comment: I wrote 'name.max' not 'max' alone

Comment: I'm aware of that. My intention was to inform you that your answer is wrong: I do _not_ have to use `name.max`.